# Mask zero values from pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with zero values and my plot looks like following:

[image]

I want to mask zero values in the plot. Following is what I am using to plot:

```
ro_list = pd.DataFrame({'Annual min' : annual_ro_min, 'Annual max': annual_ro_max})
ro_list.plot.line(grid=True, ax=ax1, ylim=(0,200), figsize=(5,5))
plt.show()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the plotting engine accepts `np.nan` values that are left out. `0`s are plotted normally.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([{
    'A' : .5,
    'B' : .5
},{
    'A' : 1,
    'B' : 2
},{
    'A' : 2,
    'B' : 0
},{
    'A' : 1,
    'B' : 2
},{
    'A' : 0,
    'B' : 1
}])

df.replace(0, np.nan).plot()
```

[image: replacement]

If you want to connect the lines around missing data, you could use

```
df[np.logical_and(df.A != 0, df.B != 0)].plot()
```

[image]

or

```
df[df.A != 0].plot()
df[df.B != 0].plot()
```

[image]

note, that in the last plot, the light blue line connects between `1` and `3`

Answer (score 0):

you can use pipeline

```
(ro_list.query(' "Annual min"!=0 and "Annual max"!=0 ')
        .plot.line()
)
```

Comment: ro_list is dataframe, however, code above, will just remove zero data, maybe you want plot.bar

Comment: I am getting long list of errors with above code: 
`(ro_list.query(' "Annual min"!=0 and "Annual max"!=0 ')
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2052, in query
    res = self.eval(expr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2104, in eval` ................

Comment: sorry my fault. column names should not include space character.

(ro_list.query(' Annual_min!=0 and Annual_max!=0 ')
        .plot.line()
)